# MSBuild ResolveAssemblyReference task is very slow after loading Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild

I am starting MSBuild using .NET code to build C# projects.

For a small test project, it takes less than a second to run the build process.  However, after I load Visual Studio (2013) I find it takes almost 8 seconds for the exact same build.  The slowness then persists until I reboot.  After a clean reboot, but before loading VS it is fast, but once I load VS it is slower again, a lot slower.  In both cases the build is successful.  I find the same problem still exists with VS2015 (darn).  The problem can be reproduced starting MSBuild directly from a command prompt.

I ran the two scenarios with MSBuild /verbosity:diagnostic and find the logs are similar but the time for ResolveAssemblyReference is 419ms for pre-VS and 7040ms for post-VS.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas?

Comment: I have VS2010, 13, 12, and 15 installed (for support reasons) but still doing most product development in VS2013.

Comment: Please clarify. You talk about 'loading VS', what does that entail? Just running VS? Opening a solution containing your C# projects in it? So first you run msbuikd on the command line, then you open VS, then what exactly? Do you build in VS or do you still build from the commandline? Also know that in the first case it's not *exactly* the same build as building in VS will have extra properties like 'BuildingInsideVisualStudio' defined

Comment: Loading VS means just clicking the icon to open the IDE.  I usually leave it open.  But even if I shut it down the slowness persists.  Here is the test process: 1)  build using MSBuild; time is about 1 sec. 2) load VS IDE. 3) build using MSBuild again; time is about 8 sec.

Comment: My assumption is that loading VS is changing the nature of assembly resolution process by including more search locations, but I do not know how to reset the search locations to the default.  Another factor is that I run the %VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat before running MSBuild.

Comment: Can't reproduce, so it might have to do with the kind of project you have or so. Note that with diagnostic logging, the ResolveAssemblyReference task will effectively print out all search paths and the resolved references so it's easy to see if there's any difference there.

Comment: That helps.  I retraced my steps and it appears I have to do the build in VS to cause the slowness.  Also, find this happens when the projects reference a certain assembly.  But, the exact same build are very fast before doing the VS build the first time.  BTW: when I say build, I mean /t:Rebuild.  Skipping the build because everything is up to date does not count as being "fast" ;^)  The DLL in question does contain some PNG resources and I am wondering if that could have something to do with it.  VS is definitely doing something like changing the cache or something.

Comment: Other than times, the diagnostic logs are identical.  So maybe I need to go as far as comparing SysInternals ProcMon  logs to see what is really different.  If I did not do thousands of builds a year I would let it go, but I want those 7000+ seconds back.  Its a bit of a flow killer when something that should be almost instantaneous takes almost 10 seconds.